# Open Excel file, to import data to that file, using Outlook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to set up the following process.

When I open Outlook in the morning it will look in a network folder. If the file in that folder does not have today's date as a save date open the file and import data from a chosen path then save it.

It will open Excel but it errors on `strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.PRN),*.PRN", , "Please select text file...")`.

> "Object doesn't Support this property or Method"

```
Sub Application_Startup()

   Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
   Dim sourceWB As Excel.Workbook
   Dim sourceSH As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim oXL As Excel.Application
   Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook

 'Check if file doesn't have today's date (need to write code)

  Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
      With xlApp
      .Visible = True
      .EnableEvents = True
      '.UserControl = True
      '.DisplayAlerts = True
      '.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    End With

 strFile = "S:\NFInventory\groups\CID\CID Database\BigPic Files\BigPic 2019.xlsx"

'Import process (Error starts next line)
 strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.PRN),*.PRN", , "Please select text file...")

With wb.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh
End With

 'open File
  Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , , , , , , , , True)
  Set sourceSH = sourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  sourceWB.Activate

 'Save and Close
     'Workbooks("BigPic 2019.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: error starts on this line     `strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.PRN),*.PRN", , "Please select text file...")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host application is Outlook while GetOpenFilename() is an Excel Application function

So call it via Excel application object:

```
strFile = xlApp.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.PRN),*.PRN", , "Please select text file...")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!!